# How can I introduce random values within my JavaScript background color code

Tags: javascript

So I'm working on my WordPress site and what I ran into with this background color code is that it produces the same color for every article that has the same amount of characters:

```
function setBgColor() {
    var titleLength = document.getElementsByClassName('fl-heading-text')[0].innerText.length;
    var hue = titleLength * 100 % 360;
    var bgColor = "hsl( " + hue + ", 90%, 60% )";
    document.getElementsByClassName("fl-page-content")[0].style.background = bgColor;
}
setBgColor();
```

What I am attempting to do now is add a bit of variation so that even if two or more articles have the same title length, the saturation output won't necessarily be the same.

I've attempted to modify it in the following way, but when I'm using `Math.random` I'm no longer receiving a background with color, but a white background like the code isn't working:

```
function setBgColor() {
    var titleLength = document.getElementsByClassName('fl-heading-text')[0].innerText.length;
    var hue = titleLength * 100 % 360;
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 100) + 1);
    var bgColor = "hsl( " + hue + ", " + x + ", 60% )";
    document.getElementsByClassName("fl-page-content")[0].style.background = bgColor;
}
setBgColor();
```

Thank you for helping me wrap my head around this.

Comment: What is wrong with the Math.random?

Comment: What is the desired result? What do you actually get?

Comment: I've modified my post to explain that it doesn't work means I'm getting a white background instead of a colored one as the original code outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With hsl values, the first number is a number between 0-255, and the other two numbers are percents. You need to add a percent sign after your random saturation.

```
"hsl( " + hue + ", " + x + "%, 60% )";
```